# How to open and iterate over webpages in a .sh file

Tags: linux, shell, raspberry-pi3

I have a rasberry pi running rasbian that i want to convert to a smart clock to open 3 webpages and iterate over them on startup I have the following code

```
# Open Outlook website and Time.is in fullscreen
chromium-browser --noerrdialogs --disable-session-crashed-bubble --disable-infobars --start-fullscreen https://outlook.office.com https://time.is

# List of websites to open (replace with your URLs)
websites=("https://app.datadoghq.eu")

# Iterate over the list of websites and open in new tabs
for website in "${websites[@]}"; do
    chromium-browser --new-tab "$website"
    sleep 5  # Adjust sleep time as needed
done

# Give Chromium some time to load tabs
sleep 10

# Infinite loop every 10 seconds
while true; do
    # Switch to the next tab using xdotool every 10 seconds
    xdotool key "ctrl+Tab"
    sleep 10

    # Check if the current tab is "Time.is" and stay on it for 1 minute
    current_tab_url=$(xdotool getwindowfocus getwindowname)
    if [[ $current_tab_url == *"https://time.is"* ]]; then
        sleep 50
    fi
    
    echo "Switching tabs every 10 seconds..."
    # Add your additional tasks here
done
```

It only opens outlook and time.is and does not iterate over them
Any idea of why that could be and how can i edit the code to achive what i want

Comment: Using ".sh" in a filename is bad practice -- interpreter selection is performed based on shebangs, not on filenames, and `.sh` _implies_ `#!/bin/sh`, even though people often actually use a different interpreter for shell scripts (bash, ksh, zsh, etc) that isn't fully compatible with `/bin/sh`. Indeed, you're using features that sh doesn't guarantee in your sample code (`[[` is an extension; same for arrays, same for `==` as a comparison operator)

Comment: ...so for us to know if your code _actually works_ you'd need to have a shebang so we know the actual interpreter. (Running your code through https://shellcheck.net/ will generate a warning asking for the same thing).

Comment: Beyond that, before we can identify a root cause we need to know a specific error. Incorrect interpreter selection is _one_ thing that could be wrong, but it's not the _only_ thing that could be wrong. Show us what happens when you try to run your script in a terminal (not a GUI; those often don't show any error messages at all).

Comment: (You might also think about putting `set -x` early in the script to turn on trace logging, so you can look at the actual commands invoked during execution; that way you can see if, for example, `current_tab_url` has a different value than you expect it to).

Comment: (also, for any serious browser automation project I wouldn't use bash at all; there are a _lot_ of serious browser automation tools, typically with frontends in either javascript or Python; which to use depends on why you're using it -- something like [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/), or [Playwright](https://playwright.dev/), or [Puppeteer](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/puppeteer/) is typically appropriate).

Comment: The first `chromium-browser` needs to run in the background with an ampersand at the  end of the line.